# Type restriction in props is not recognized in the function

Tags: typescript

Why is the following object extraction flagged as incorrect by the compiler? [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAymA2BLYAVCAPYAFATgezAGcAeFAGigDkoNgIA7AE0KgGsIQ8AzKFAPigBeXgG1KAXRqYGzKIWA5E9AOYBYAFBQoAfigBvDVqNQ8AIwBWEAMbAAXL0PGoyiMDo57lR1oC+j+-QQAG4QOBoaVnj08nIIyGiYQlCkFNS0MizsnDz8ABQGmiYW1sBkji5uoRo+9nBIqLS4BCTkVHwAlEICBVqR0cBQQQCG8ACu0MJmljYiFe7ijjiuozj0gyPjAHSEccC5AORQ++3V4epK7lxDVtAAIkPAD+DQPetjEPbyiiqOiIwBowAtqYquo-OoIlEYktIjh-lB7o9QJAkno3uN7PsAOJLBhQRAsZR4PCMfYUP72ACsUHBfWhEEIo3gA2EO3qCT2aKmJXsMLwcIoc1CmOG70OPhOEPUdLw8Agm3geGUuSWjOZ7SAA)

```
type SplitTextProps<T, N extends keyof T> = T[N] extends string
  ? {
      object: T
      getter: N
    }
  : never

const splitText = <T, N extends keyof T>({
  object,
  getter
}: SplitTextProps<T, N>) => {
  const value = object[getter]
  return value.split(' ')
}

interface Datatype {
  value: string
  id: number
}

const record: Datatype = { value: 'Green is good', id: 5 }
const result = splitText({ object: record, getter: 'value' })

console.log(result)
```

`value.split(' ')` is marked as incorrect despite the type definition on `SplitTextProps`. The exact error message is

> Property 'split' does not exist on type 'T[N]'

---

**Edit (Adding more info):** In fact, the restriction actually works when trying to pass *incorrect* props, the compiler throws the following error when trying to use `splitText({object: record, getter : 'id'})`

> Argument of type '{ object: Datatype; getter: string }' is not assignable to parameter type 'never'.

☝️ because `id` prop of `interface Datatype` isn't a `string`. Only the happy path fails within `splitText` func .

Comment: Generic conditional types like `SplitTextProps<T, N>` inside the body of `splitText()` are essentially opaque to the compiler (see [ms/TS#48243](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48243) for example).  You'll be happier if you refactor not to use such types; I'd try [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w6Lpym) instead. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: , in other words define the object with only the key that I am interested in, is that correct?

Comment: Right, unless your use case requires that `T` be generic (which you can [still do](https://tsplay.dev/NlLlRN)).  The main idea is that the compiler understands that `Record<K, V>[K]` is assignable to `V`, since that's an index into a mapped type and not a conditional type.  So should I write up an answer or am I missing something about the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that the TypeScript compiler cannot generally follow "higher order" logical operations with as-yet-unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types.  Inside the body of `splitText()`, the type `SplitTextProps<T, N>` is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depends on generic type parameters `T` and `N`.  When the compiler tries evaluates the type of `object` and `getter`, it takes the shortcut of widening the conditional type to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of its true and false branches, so it becomes `{ object, getter } : { object: T, getter: N }`.  Then `value` is of type `T[N]`, which is correct. But notably, any information about `T[N] extends string` has unfortunately been lost.  So `value.split()` is an error.

On the other hand, *callers* of `splitText()` usually don't have this problem.  When you call `splitText({ object: record, getter: 'value' })`, the compiler can infer that you are specifying `T` as `DataType` and `N` as `"value"`.  And therefore that the input is of type `SplitTextProps<DataType, "value">` which can be evaluated directly to be `{ object: DataType, getter: "value" }`, and it type checks.  If you call it some with some unexpected input, you'll likely get `SplitTextProps<SomeT, SomeN>` evaluating to `never`, and you get the expected error.

In short: unresolved generic conditional types are hard to deal with, so callers using specific types tend to be happy, and implementers using generic types can sometimes be unhappy.

---

If you want to leave things as-is, and you're sure you've implemented things properly, you could just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to the compiler that `value` is a `string`:

```
const splitText = <T, N extends keyof T>(
  { object, getter }: SplitTextProps<T, N>
) => {
  const value = object[getter] as string; // <-- assert
  return value.split(' '); // okay
}
```

Otherwise, you'd need to refactor to a form the compiler can evaluate more correctly.  Personally, I would stay away from conditional types unless they are necessary to represent your operation.  For the code example as given, I'd be inclined to write it this way:

```
type SplitTextProps<N extends PropertyKey> = {
  object: Record<N, string>, getter: N
}

const splitText = <N extends PropertyKey>(
  { object, getter }: SplitTextProps<N>
) => {
  const value = object[getter];
  return value.split(' '); // okay
}
```

Here, `SplitTextProps` only cares directly about the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of `getter` `N`, while your `T` has been replaced with `Record<N, string>`, using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype).  The compiler is able to understand that `Record<K, V>[K]` is assignable to `V`, even for generic `K`.  So then `value` is seen of a type assignable to `string`, and you are allowed to call `split()` on it.

Of course whether or not you can refactor your conditional type to something else that the compiler understands depends strongly on the use case, so there are probably times when a type assertion is your easiest and most straightforward solution.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBBKUICcAuSDeAUEktgJ4zIDKMANgJbYAqEAHtgAqYD2MUAPIwA0SAHJJW2CMAAmUJAGsIpLgDMkjAHxIAvOoDaIgLri2U2UijZMdYAHMixJAH58Dx0i4AjAFYR42AC51N0dbCGxJTCCREIBfEKDgCAA3LAIHeC5gSwtaBmY2HSQBYTEJMzlFZTVNAApCdy9ff0EQsIi04lig6nomCU4efiFRDQBKHS0Gx0zs3GSQGgBXZF0mv2w9dsjjEDlLazsAbiQAelPigFpLpD2MHBDMcKXMYCQF5YgAOlg+2oByJD-MYOeIOGyRFQIZAAERA2Hh5GQ02IHxWQQONns7jo0kSSzAnk6SDBxFmOSemUweKQcIRZAoRTw70W6KBAHEnlIkHQ5LYuFxpP9hLiggBWEkZLIU6BLGi4XS-fISeoeHwbIKUrjU4TbLBBf5oiCA2IgqXZLg0b40Li2WpPKBy7AgsGgSCwaFIACSMlYEGkKHgiHQAHlgDRSK50sQGVQ8v02INeHwyqYZHIk1gyABpJRaXQotXNQJIABKfm10hTwkxdg0uvCkWioOjSHJuCVCYVxVTknTSEzOFIudIGnqIXWLTajeJ3SQvWVie4yZE40mrnc7ZZnyKk82eswhiOj2er23Kx+8YBQLGJ3OHnkIFILfBwEhnrpiMZhaNGKsWJCUUkGAAkiUwF8yWlXAtWpIJP1jJlzwgA1OQgbleSQflBWFHkaQleJILmJAHSdIpOwKbBVT3TUKx1TCZyiIEjRNM1CKgS1rVte1ZXlM1YiAA)